# Swift - Widget background transparent

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, widgetkit

I am trying to set background color for my app widget to transparent, but having some issues.

It works fine by setting a color: `.background(Color.white)`

But I cant figure out how to make it transparent like this:
[image]

I've tried like this: `.background(Color.white.opacity(0.5))` but that just makes it gray. Any help please?

Comment: I'd assume it's a private API, but I could be wrong. If it is private, it would be similar to transparency in Safari for example, where only system apps can do that.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with George.

Currently the only way to make a transparent widget is to add a relevant part of the home screen wallpaper (based on widget location) as an image for a widget.
This way a widget will look like a fully transparent one, but only when there are no screen movements / animations